# Weird form behavior

Tags: jquery

i'm having some crazy trouble and i can't figure out how to fix it. I have a form that has a "return submitNotes" on the submit button (onclick). i have the submitNotes function and it seems to be calling it fine, but in my function i have an ajax call that doesn't seem to be firing off. I've placed alerts in the ajax call for when it is finished and the curious thing is that the alert only goes off when i have return false at the bottom of the page. If i comment out the return it doesn't even show the alert. In both cases the ajax call doesn't seem to be reaching out to it's page. Anything you guys can do to help!

```
function submitNotes(rID){

    ts = getTs(); //this is so IE sees a unique URL being called everytime.
    var consignor = $('#consignor').val()
    var consignee = $('#consignee').val();
    var consignorRequired = $('#consignorRequired').val();

    if(consignorRequired=='true'){

            if(consignor==''){
                alert('Consignor information is required!');
                return false;
            }

            if(consignee==''){
                alert('Consignee information is required!');
                return false;
            }
    }

    $('#loading_notes').show();

    $.get('/scripts/claim_sendTo.asp?action=pending&rID='+rID+'&auditorID=1',function(){
        alert('hello2');
        $('#claimForm').submit();
    });

    //return false;

}
```

Comment: why vote to close? What's too localized about this question? It's a pretty common issue people run into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the alert goes off when you uncomment `return false` because you're in the context of a onsubmit event. Returning `false` from that event cancels it, allowing your jquery to execute. Otherwise, the form reloads the page

Comment: i changed submit button to a link and called the function on a onclick, but it still doesn't execute the ajax call. I have that call somewhere else on a page and it works fine there. I've even copied and pasted the code from one to the other but nothing

Comment: You didn't need to do anything other than uncomment out the `return false` statement. Watch to see if the AJAX call is going out in the net tab of firebug or in IE dev tools network tab, or by using fiddler. If you're seeing the alert "hello2" that means your ajax call went out.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to try is preventing the event's default behaviour.

You may want to use onsubmit="" on the form instead of onclick="" because then you can stop the form submission at the core.

Then, you'll want to pass the event object to the submit function. It allows for greater control over the event without relying too much on return values.

```
<form method="post" action="X" onsubmit="submitNotes(event)">

// Somewhere in your JavaScript
function submitNotes(event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    else window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    // the rest of the event code
}
```

That should be a good start.

If you want to stick with using the `onclick` event, you may want to try the following:

```
<form method="post" action="X" onsubmit="if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); else window.event.cancelBubble = true">
```

That should prevent the form from handling submission.

Could I recommend you use jQuery's `$('form').submit( ... )` event handling?

Comment: It does reload the page but it does go into the code. If i put the alert after the loading_notes.show, it'll show up. It's when it's in the $.get request that it doesn't work.